# Creating multiple masks for a single image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create the following scenario, and I'm willing to use any combination of jquery, css, and html possible (I'd like to stay away from HTML 5 right now however, but I'm willing to look at it if it is the only solution).

I would like to have a large image ONLY viewable where the masks lie on it. I've tried multiple techniques, none of which work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Will the masks or image move around, or always stay in those positions? What techniques did you try?

Comment: @Emmett, the masks will move around, but the image will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple method is to have the image set as a `background-image` on the "windows", which are absolutely positioned within `#maskContainer`. `top` and `left` are set, and `background-position` is set to match.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XjCCK/
(view in a WebKit browser so the `background-position` animation works; it's purely for the demo)

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="maskContainer">
    <div class="window static"></div>
    <div class="window moving"></div>
</div>
```

​**CSS:**

```css
#maskContainer {
    background: #000;
    width: 603px;
    height: 482px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.window {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/j9a2T.jpg) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}
.static {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    background-position: -20px -30px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var maskContainerWidth = $('#maskContainer').width(),
    maskContainerHeight = $('#maskContainer').height();

setInterval(function() {
    $('.moving').each(function() {
        var width = Math.floor(Math.random()*maskContainerWidth),
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*maskContainerHeight),
            left = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maskContainerWidth-width)),
            top = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maskContainerHeight-height));

        $(this).animate({
            width: width,
            height: height,
            left: left,
            top: top,
            backgroundPositionX: -left,
            backgroundPositionY: -top
        }, 1000);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Needed a little tweaking for non-webkit, but pretty much exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently you can't animate `background-position` on Firefox. It doesn't support `background-position-x` (or y) and animate only works on numeric properties

Comment: @ori: Correct. That's why I said "view in a WebKit browser so the background-position animation works; it's purely for the demo". The OP didn't say he actually *wanted* to animate this. Anyway, the problem is easy to solve. I probably should have mentioned it in my original answer instead of being lazy. [There's a plugin, as always.](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) You should update your answer in the other question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not treat everything around your "masking divs" as the mask (because that's what it really is).  Use either an image with transparent holes (where your masking divs are) or grid of opaque divs with transparent divs for your "masking divs).  Put this image/grid over the background image.  This should give you a lot of flexibility with moving the windows to the background image.

Comment: Well part of the problem with this technique is that the mask moves around.