# Animating a div with a background image from right to left

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that is essentially acting as a mask for its background image by only revealing the a specific portion of the image.

The background image is aligned to the right. I am attempting to animate the backgroundPosition from the right to the left, HOWEVER, the animation automatically resets the background position to the left (or very near left - I can't quite figure out where the position is coming from).

Is there any way to overcome this?

Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/QRkLr/

(notice that when the animation fires the background image is NOT aligned perfectly to the right).

Comment: You could have a static position for the background, and not have to change it when the div moves

Comment: @Mikhail I'm not quite sure what you mean. How would I apply that?

Comment: @kylex Can you explain more in depth what you are hoping to achieve? Are you hoping to have the mask go to the left until it can't be seen anymore?

Comment: @Wasbazi: The position of the background image is not aligned all the way to the right when the animation starts. I need it to be aligned to the right.

Comment: @Wasbazi: Here's a link to the previous question, maybe it will help to show the intent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354321/creating-multiple-masks-for-a-single-image. (I don't have time to answer this question at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

The initial X position of your mask has to be a number, not "right". If I'm not mistaken, any number (percent or pixel) assigned to `background-position` is calculated from the left.

So my fix is: keep the css: `background-position: top right;`, but then before the animation, calculate the required initial X position from the left, and then animate back to 0 (left):

```
$("#image").css({backgroundPositionX: -large_left_border})
     .animate({backgroundPositionX: 0}, 1500);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRkLr/9/)

**EDIT**

Bottom line: `background-position-x` isn't supported by Firefox, and `.animate()` only works on numeric css properties (so it doesn't work on `background-position` because it's not a single number), so there's no standard jquery way to accomplish this.

However, as @thirtydot points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354321/creating-multiple-masks-for-a-single-image/9355645#comment11831626_9355645), there is a plugin that implements animation on `background-position`: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Comment: This does not animate the background in FireFox.

Comment: I guess [you're right](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y),  backgroundPositionX isn't supported on firefox. And `animate`  method only works on numeric CSS properties. Looks like a dead end.