# How to Convert undefined to integer value? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, background

My problem is that I am using the `.hover` method to get the x position of a background-img. When i ask `typeof` it returns as undefined. When i ask it to alert me the returned value it gives me: "10px", how can I make this an integer value that gets stored in the variable properly?

My function goes as follows:

```
$("#menu li").hover(  
    function () { 
        var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x')   
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: xPos + "px 0px"
         }, 500); 
    },  

    function () {
        var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x')   
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition:  xPos + "px 35px"
        }, 500); 
    }
);
```

Comment: In the future, please use the code button in the editor (**`{}`**) to format your code.

Comment: Note that `background-position-x` is not a standard and it's not supported in all browsers.

Comment: First of all, I'm pretty sure you can't use jQuery animate on a property that has multiple values. One value at a time in the animate method.

Comment: Oh no the reason i need the x value, is because i am using one image, for multiple menu items, the x position is the value that is not going to change. I just need the image to up and down, hence only the y value is changing.

Comment: Don't use `background-position-x`/`background-position-y`, unless you like it when your code breaks in Firefox (and possibly also other browsers). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354321/creating-multiple-masks-for-a-single-image/9355645#9355645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the 'px'

```
var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x').slice(0, -2);
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `parseInt(xPos, 10)`.

Comment: Since he was placing it into a string and not using it for numerical comparison I figured this would work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

You may find the parseInt() function is what you're looking for: http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

`var xPos = parseInt($(this).css('background-position-x'));`

That will evaluate the string until it runs into a non-number character.  So 10px will become 10.

However, if all you're using it for is the function you've written, you could probably just take off the first "px" that you're concatenating and it should work:

```
var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x');
$(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: xPos + " 0"}, 500);
```

Comment: +1, however `parseFloat` would be better, since some browsers store in floating point notation.  in general, `parseInt` has been optimized by the browser, I think `parseFloat` as well.